# Para que serve o ob_start do php?

Tags: php

Eu vi que ele põe todos os dados processados em buffer, e libera quando completar.

O que é buffer exatamente? Só vi esse nome em players, que é o tamanho do arquivo que será alocado em memória a partir do ponto atual do vídeo/áudio.

O que eu entendi, é que a página só é liberada quando os dados estiverem todos processados, tipo, vai tudo de uma vez para o client. É isso mesmo?

Comment: A duvida é boa, por isso dei +1 na pergunta, mas é basicamente o que foi respondido no link indicado, por isso o fechamento indicando a solução. Vale notar que o prefixo ob_ é justamente "output buffer"